# Output items.categories inside a Repeated Section

Tags: squarespace

I can't figure out how to output the categories from a `collection.items`. I can loop through the collection.categories `{.repeated section categories}{name}{.end}` but when I try to do the same thing a level deeper on the `collection.items.categories` to output  the categories for each individual item using the same syntax. Nothing is outputted.

```
{.repeated section items}
  {.repeated section categories}{name}{.alternates with} / {.end}
{.end}
```

But using the json formatter `categories|json-pretty` instead of `{name}` does what I need and spits out the categories for each item. I seem to be missing the key.

**code example:**

```
<!--WORKS-->

<squarespace:category collection="team">
  {.if categories}
   <div class="button-group filter-button-group">
     <button data-filter="*">All</button>
     {.repeated section categories}<button data-filter=".{name}">{name}</button>{.end}
   </div>
  {.end}
</squarespace:category>

<!--DOES NOT WORK-->

<section class="grid">
  <squarespace:query collection="team" limit="100">
    {.repeated section items}
     <div class="grid-item">
      <img {customContent.teamImage|image-meta}/>
      <h3>{customContent.teamName}</h3>
      {.repeated section categories}{name}{.alternates with} / {.end}
     </div>
    {.end}
  </squarespace:query>
</section>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inside of `{.repeated section categories}` you should use `{@}` to refer to the key you've scoped into. For example:

`{.repeated section categories}{@}{.alternates with} / {.end}`

Reference: https://developers.squarespace.com/templating-basics#ReferencingtheScope

> Using scope reference, written as {@}, allows you to reference the key
>   you're scoped into. This is like `(this)` in JavaScript.

Comment: Funny. I tried that. But I must have made a syntax mistake for something since it didn't work. Thank you Brandon.